# Have wrong output of numpy.linalg.solve

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use python to solve a matrix function Ax=b. In this case, we have

```
A = [[-1.  1.  0.]
     [-1.  0.  1.]
     [-2.  0.  0.]]
b = [ 1.  1.  2.]
```

I was trying to use `numpy.linalg.solve` to solve this as my code below

```
result = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

the output is like this

```
[ -1.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16   2.22044605e-16]
```

which is apparently different from the correct answer.
So I tried to implement this in the terminal as below

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> T = np.matrix([[-1.0,1.0,0.0],[-1.0,0.0,1.0],[-2.0,0.0,0.0]])
>>> b = np.array([1.0,1.0,2.0])
>>> np.linalg.solve(T,b)
array([-1.,  0.,  0.])
>>> type(b[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

I am thinking about the data type may cause this kind of result, but both A and b from my code are 'numpy.float64'. So I can't figure out what's the reason of this situation.

Comment: Looks fine to me. (Note the `e-16`s.)

Comment: First comment is correct. For fun: add ```np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)``` after importing numpy and observe. Look up scientific-notation and numpy's docs if still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that it's a solution by doing the following

```
r = np.linalg.solve(T,b)
T@r  # Matrix mutiplication if you have a modern python
```

This will return the b vector you had.